# Trying to take user input and write to a file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i'm having a problem where I am trying to save the geolocation of an address unto a file.  I am using hidden labels to transfer the information.

on the client side button event I have:

```
   function save() {
        document.getElementById("hidLat").value = y;
        document.getElementById("hidLon").value = x;
        <% saveAddress s = save(); %>
   }
```

and in c# I have:

```
   protected saveAddress save()
   {
        saveAddress s = new saveAddress();
        s.latitude = hidLat.Value;
        s.longitude = hidLon.Value;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\\savedAddresses.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(s.latitude + " " + s.longitude);
            file.Close();
        }  

        return s;
   }
```

When I click on the button the file is created but nothing is saved into it.
Am I doing this right or is there a better way to try and write the user input into a file?

Comment: `<% saveAddress s = save(); %>` is executed by the server, before s.latitude and s.longitude are filled, so they return blank,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting confused on the web lifecycle. In your particular instance, this is what is happening:

1. Your page is requested, and the ASP.NET Runtime loads your code behind and attempts to execute the page.
2. In the process of executing your page, the ASPX contains code to call

   ```
    saveAddress s = save()
   ```

   In this way, that method is called before the page is even rendered back to the client.
3. When the page is finally sent down to the client, you have some client side code invoking `function save()`.

Im guessing you want that server side method to be invoked after the javascript function has run. You have two options:

1. Full PostBack - You post the form back to the server, and your ASPX code behind can have some code there to inspect `Page.IsPostBack` and attempt to call your server side method.
2. Ajax - You can make an ajax request to a specific handler on your site and then invoke your server side `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the latitude and longitude variables are set? Try printing them out first..
Code seems OK

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are confused about about transferring values between server and client code. Seeing the markup would be useful. I am assuming you are using webforms `<asp:Label />` control. In order to transfer values to the server you need to post a form or make an `XMLHttpRequest.` There are other ways but we will just stick with these two for now.

Also remember that if these labels are server controls their values are stored in viewstate. Modifying the value with javascript will not affect the view state. I would recommend storing the values in a hidden form input field. Add your save logic to a save `OnClick` server side.

Answer (score 0):

Comment

You don't want to use

```
file.Close();
```

when you use "using(){}"